# Best way to upgrade Yocto Version

Tags: yocto

I am using an older Yocto version on a custom hardware.
My plan is to upgrade this version to a more recent one (e.g Zeus)
What would be the best approach in doing this ?
Should I just compare the two versions and shift files from the older version to the newer one or
start from scratch on the newer one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the amount of modifications you have done so far, and hopefully you did all  of them into your custom meta layer only.
However as general rule you can start from scratch on Zeus and include your custom meta layer to see what's going wrong.